# Positioning content relative to background with background-position:cover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a neat little landing page for a site. I have an excellent 1920x1080 image, that has a nice open space in the middle which is *perfect* for putting the content in.

I am using the `background-size: cover;` attribute to ensure my background scales nicely and never appears warped, however I'm having trouble figuring out how to line up the page content with the background when the screen is re-sized due to the odd mechanics of background-size: cover.

I've whipped up an example page to demonstrate what I mean: http://umwh.at/test.html. Viewed in 1920x1080, the content more or less aligns up perfectly with the background image, but when scaled down it doesn't work well at all.

So, without further ado, my question is: **Is it possible to achieve this using purely CSS?**

(Side note: I have a solution using javascript [here (Warning, large image)](http://timeofeve.dogcla.ws/) but I've been told it's not the right way to go about it, but I haven't been able to figure out another way).

Comment: I don't see any images in your test

Comment: @Danield I was referring to the white and black background image test.png.

Comment: Ahh on the html element ok

Comment: maybe you need to use background-size: contain;

Comment: With `background-size: contain` I'd lose a lot of area for putting content in :(

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    background: #EEE url('../img/test.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Referece : http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Demo : http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php

Comment: Unfortunately in this example the content is fixed width and not dependant on the scaling of the background image so it doesn't help me :(